# MySQL query encompassing two fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My two tables, with only the relevant values included, are:

- xx_users (user_id, name, location)
- xx_posts (post, user_id)

xx_users contains all users, including the current user and the poster.

In mock code, what I am trying to achieve is:

```
SELECT * FROM xx_posts WHERE poster location = user location
```

Given the crossover between the two tables, how would I approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I well understood your question, the solution can be something like :

`SELECT * from posts INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id = posts.user_id WHERE users.location = 'the location`'

Answer (score 1):

If I've understoood the question correctly, you want to see all posts which were posted by a user who shares alocation with the current user (or another given user). In which case:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM xx_posts p 
INNER JOIN xx_users poster ON p.user_id = poster.user_id 
INNER JOIN xx_users currentuser ON u1.location = u2.location
WHERE currentuser.user_id = <the id of the user you're interested in>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do u want this?

```
SELECT p.post,p.user_id,...
FROM xx_posts as p
INNER JOIN xx_users as u
ON p.user_id=u.user_id
WHERE p.location = u.location
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: There's no 'location' field in xxx_posts.

Answer (score 0):

To get the intersection of two sets, use `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.name, a.location, b.post
FROM xx_posts b
INNER JOIN xx_users a ON a.user_id = b.user_id
```

### [See it in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a2ba/1)

To filter based on location, add:

```
WHERE a.location = 'Alaska'
```

It's also best practice to specify a column list, and avoid using `SELECT *`.

**`INNER JOIN`**

[image]